# JPA Get Entry by Timestamp

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to retrieve all record today from an entity class using jpa.

My entity class has a date created property.

```
public class SingleTripDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private SingleTripDetailsStatus status = SingleTripDetailsStatus.MATCHED;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp dateCreated;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = true)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastModified;
}
```

I am trying to get all records by the `dateCreated` property.

```
public List<SingleTripDetails> findByStatusAndDateCreated(SingleTripDetailsStatus status, Timestamp date);
```

I do the following in my data service class

```
public List<SingleTripDetails> getAmountMadeToday(Date date, String email) {
        return driverRiderApplicationRepository.findByStatusAndDateCreated(SingleTripDetailsStatus.ENDED, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
    }

but it does not work. What could I be doing wrong?
```

Comment: You should be using Java 8 Time API.

Comment: `Timestamp` can go down to nanoseconds. Might be easiest if you did a timestamp range or pruned off the nano and looked for either only the date or hours and minutes.

Comment: Timestamp holds the Date and Time as well. But your method name suggests you want any from today. You can't use JpaRepository because it will check for exact date and time.

Comment: @George do I change the variable `dateCreated` to a `Util.Date`? or do I write sql query manually?

Comment: How date is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handling Date is a very tricky part, a Timestamp can save up to the precision of nanoseconds.

let's look at your repository method

```
driverRiderApplicationRepository.findByStatusAndDateCreated(
```

This is going to do an exact match on Status and DateCreated, without knowing data saved in DB, I am just assuming date are being stored with time.

As I understand you want all amount made today, I would suggest (for me safest way)you change your repository method like below

```
findByStatusAndDateCreatedBetween(Statustype status, Timestamp t1, Timestamp t2)
```

now

in **Timestamp t1:** `provide a date with time as 00:00`

in **Timestamp t2:** `provide the same date with time as 23:59`